# How to access all controls on lightswitch page

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have to perform a common validation task on each control on a lightswitch page such that when a user interacts with the control then a another control on the page is cleared. I have no idea how to iterate the controls on the page without calling

```
 this.FindControl("MyId")
```

For each individual control and then setting up a handler on ControlAvailable and then get the control and bind to the correct event so that I can do something somewhere else on the page.

Is there a way to loop all controls and test for presence of the type TextBox rather than looking having to find each control by name explicitely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/65b146d3-2bee-44ed-a4e6-e54383627756/

Cheers,

Paul